# Is Near-infrared focused light safe for your eyes?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, radiation, safety

I found a new product, but I'm afraid it's not safe. Can you help me understand what the safety limits are when it comes to near-infrared light focused on your eyes is?

I'm assuming the wavelength of the light is important, but probably more important is the amount of focus. (For instance, visible light isn't very dangerous unless it's focused in a laser).

Product: http://theeyetribe.com/

Here is their quote about safety on the FAQ:

> Yes, The Eye Tribe Tracker complies with the essential health and
>   safety requirements set by the FCC and CE directives. The Eye Tribe
>   Tracker is using near-infrared illumination, it conforms with the EN
>   62471 standard and we have obtained an EU declaration of conformity.
>   Our hardware has been tested and approved by a certified lab according
>   to said standard, and is therefore safe to use.

Related question:
[Is it safe to look at infrared LEDs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13691/is-it-safe-to-look-at-infrared-leds)

Comment: Unfortunately, **personal medical questions and health advice** are off-topic on Biology. We cannot safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should **always consult a doctor for medical advice**.

Comment: I understand. In that case: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/is-near-infrared-focused-light-safe-for-your-eyes